# Is "line feed" without "carriage return" possible in HTML?

Tags: html, css, newline

An example text:

```
And you, 
         could you have played 
                               a nocturne
On a waterspout for a flute?
```

It's an extract from a poem by [Vladimir Mayakovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Mayakovsky), illustrating his signature "ladder-shaped" strophe.

Original:

```
А вы
     ноктюрн сыграть
                     могли бы
На флейте водосточных труб?
```

Another example:

```
Простенького паренька
подцепила
          барынька.
Он работать,
             а ее
                  не удержать никак -
бегает за клёшем
                 каждого бульварника.
Что ж,
       сиди
            и в плаче
                      Нилом нилься.
```

Basically there are line feeds without carriage return. I use pre-formatted text to show the concept. Is it possible in HTML to implement that for regular proportional font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You could try using positive and negative vertical alignment in various span elements:]

Edited after OP comments.

If you can put up with wrapping it in a div and adding paragraphs, you could use symbols for the line feeds and loop through them automatically:

```js
str = $('#input').html();
str = str.replace(/\^/, '<span>').replace(/\^/g, '</span><span>').replace(/<\/p>/, '</span><\/p>');
console.log(str);
$('#output').html(str);
para = $('#output p');
para.each(function() {
  span = $(this).find('span');
  for (var j = 0; j < span.length; j++) {
    span[j].style.verticalAlign = -90 * (j + 1) + '%';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" style="display:none">
  <p>А вы ^ноктюрн сыграть ^могли бы</p>
  <p>На флейте водосточных труб?</p>
  <p>А вы ^ноктюрн сыграть ^могли бы</p>
  <p>На флейте водосточных труб?</p>
  <p>А вы ^ноктюрн сыграть ^могли бы</p>
  <p>На флейте водосточных труб?</p>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

[You will probably need to play around with the percentages to get it exactly the way you want.]

Comment: Well, that's an option, but it assumes a lot of tedious work even for a single poem, since you need to tinker align percentages manually for every line. Considering the "right ones" percentages are obvious - every next line should start right where the previous was finished - is there any way to automate this task? Ideally I want some kind of special symbol to indicate a line feed - "And you, ^could you have played ^a nocturne".

Comment: It's quite mysterious why the accepted solution would be one involving JS, when it can all be done in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with nested inline blocks with top margins.

```css
span { 
  margin-top: 1em; 
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top; 
}
```

```html
<div>А вы<span>ноктюрн сыграть<span>могли бы</span></span></div>
<div>На флейте водосточных труб?</div>
```

The logic for converting your desired `^` marks into this nested spans format would be:

```
function preprocess(poem) {
  return poem.replace(/\^.*$/m, function(m) { 
    return "<span>" + preprocess(m.slice(1)) + "</span>"; 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make each line as many `float: left` divs as required.

- Div 1 holds `And you,`
- Div 2 holds `<br>could you...`
- Div 3 holds `<br><br>a nocturne`

That way should deal with any poem, assuming you can parse it correctly on input / import.

```css
div { float: left; }
```

```html
<div>And you,</div>
<div><br>could you have played</div>
<div><br><br>a nocturne</div>
```

Comment: Sorry - I always forget to do code properly:
Should read: Div 1 holds And you, Div 2 holds 
<br>could you... Div 3 holds <br><br>a nocturne

a nocturne

Comment: And sorry again - each div should be style="float:left; width:auto; display:inline-block" apart frrom the first div wich should be clear:both instead of float:left

Comment: You can edit your answer to add new info instead of posting comments. But `width: auto` is already the default value, and `float: left` blockifies `display:inline-block` into `display:block`. So it's not needed.

Comment: Yes, Oriol, you're right - the simpler answer is just display:inline-block and it looks like torazaburo has a far neater answer